# Paypal Adaptive - 3 way paments (without taking the user to Paypal site)

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

We would like to configure our shopping carts to leverage Paypal Adaptive - 3 way payments.
However we do not want the user to be redirected to the Paypal site to approve the payment.

Are there any options to leverage (Paypal Adaptive - 3 way payments) in a seamless manner?

Reference Paypal documentation (page 71):
https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_adaptivepayments.pdf

> "Making a Chained Payment (XML)
>   A chained payment is when a sender sends a payment to a PayPal-registered receiver who is 
>   the primary receiver.
>   You send a PayRequest, enabling the primary receiver.
>   You receive a response with a pay key.
>   You must redirect the sender’s browser to PayPal to approve the payment."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to bypass the redirect to PayPal for the sender to approve a Chained Payment.  You can use Preapprovals to bypass any redirect for subsequent payments but even with Preapprovals the sender would initially need to be sent to PayPal to approve the Preapproval Agreement.